# How do I limit a SQL stored procedure to be run by one person

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that basically inserts from one table to another.

While this procedure is running, I don't want anyone else to be able to start it, however I don't want serialization, the other person to run the procedure after I am done with it.

What I want is for the other person trying to start it to get an error, while I am running the procedure.

I've tried with using sp_getapplock, however I can't manage to completely stop the person from running the procedure.

I also tried finding the procedure with sys.dm_exec_requests and blocking the procedure, while this does work, i think it's not optimal because on some servers I don't have the permissions to run  sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle).

What is the best way for me to do this?

Comment: First thing that pops to my head is. At the begining of the procedure create a table that will work as as lock. First you check if this table exists, if not create one. Then do rest of the stuff and delete table. In this table you could store information like who is executing procedure, at what time etc.

Comment: Using SET LOCK_TIMEOUT to a low value can be a part of the solution, will mean that you get error 1222 after waiting more than x ms for a lock. As for the "can't manage to completely stop the person from running the procedure" when using sp_getapplock, I can't comment. We need more info or preferably a repro on that.

Comment: Do you mean as an auxiliary empty table? Could you give me an example?

Comment: Isn't sp_getapplock just to stop concurrency? After the lock is released, another person that executed the procedure starts it automatically right?

Answer (score 0):

Cunning stunts:

```
ALTER PROC MyProc
AS
BEGIN TRY
  IF OBJECT_ID('tembdb..##lock_proc_MyProc') IS NOT NULL
    RAISERROR('Not now.', 16, 0)
  ELSE
    EXEC('CREATE TABLE ##lock_proc_MyProc (dummy int)')
  ...

  EXEC('DROP TABLE ##lock_proc_MyProc')
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  ...    
  EXEC('DROP TABLE ##lock_proc_MyProc')
  ...
END CATCH
GO
```

Which can be extended by storing spid and watching for zombie ##.

Also you can just raise isolation level/granularity like `TABLOCK`, `UPDLOCK`:

```
ALTER PROC MyProc
AS
BEGIN TRAN
  DECLARE @dummy INT
  SELECT @dummy=1
  FROM t (TABLOCKX, HOLDLOCK)
  WHERE 1=0

  ...
COMMIT TRAN
```

this will have different effect - will wait, not fall.

Comment: Dynamic - to minimize chances for recompiles caused by temp tables usage. Note, this one is `##` , not `#`. @GordonLinoff